# How to get Text from this HTML code By using Selenium WebDriver with Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

HTML Code

```
<label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RadPanelBar1_i0_chkColumns_21">Royality Free</label>
```

Selenium Code

```
driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RadPanelBar1_i0_chkColumns_21")).getText();
```

The above selenium code is not working even i tried getAttribute();
its showing NullPointerException

Comment: Can you please post webpage url or complete HTML code snippet?

Comment: One option would be to use its its parent or ancestors to reach label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to read text from the label but you are finding an element which has id `ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RadPanelBar1_i0_chkColumns_21` This is not the id of the label.

Your code should be:

```
WebElement labelElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("label[for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RadPanelBar1_i0_chkColumns_21"]"));
System.out.println(labelElement.getText());
```

This should work.

Moreover, the locator: `ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RadPanelBar1_i0_chkColumns_21` **seems** to be a randomly generated locator. Just confirm that it's not such a case. If it is then you will need to change your locating strategy.